# Homebrew: using Python modules from previous version (v3.9 -> v.3.8)

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I updated to Python 3.9 with homebrew, now all modules that I had installed are not being found due to their location being inside Python 3.8 folder. Do I have to install everything again? Or can I somehow import them to the new Python version?

```
ζ which python3
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3

ζ which pip3
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/pip3
```

```
ζ l /usr/local/opt/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 antonioaraujo  admin    28B Jan 12 16:12 /usr/local/opt/python -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 antonioaraujo  admin    28B Jan 12 16:12 /usr/local/opt/python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 antonioaraujo  admin    28B Jan 12 16:12 /usr/local/opt/python@3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 antonioaraujo  admin    26B Jan 12 16:46 /usr/local/opt/python@3.8 -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 antonioaraujo  admin    28B Jan 12 16:12 /usr/local/opt/python@3.9 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6
```

Answer (score 3):

To bring over exactly the same packages, with their same versions, use `pip freeze` and `pip install`.

Do this with the old version:

```
/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/pip3 freeze > /tmp/modules.txt
```

and this with the new version:

```
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/pip3 install -r /tmp/modules.txt
```

If you don't want to bring over everything, you can edit the /tmp/modules.txt file before you use it to install into the new Python.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: In many cases, I don't think using same package versions across Python versions should be considered a safe operation